Interpolating xarray dimension, unique to each gridpoint
I have this code working, that takes an xarray dataset with x,y and pressure level dimensions and interpolates the value of the data (in this case temperature) to a new pressure level (950). This code is working perfectly, however, if you make upper_press an array instead of a singular value, xarray cannot do the interpolation.
For instance, I want to interpolate gridpoint 1 to 950, 2 to 940, 3 to 930 and 4 to 920. I have tried messing around with xarray's apply_ufunc function but to no avail.
In this example, if we were to interpolate all the points to the 950 level, I should get returning a 2 by 2 array with values 2.5, 4.5, 1.5, 3.5
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

temp = np.array([[[2, 3], [4, 5]], [[1, 2], [3, 4]]], dtype=np.float32)

isobaricInhPa = [1000, 900]

latitude = np.linspace(10.0, 20.0, 2 * 2).reshape(2, 2)
longitude = np.linspace(20.0, 30.0, 2 * 2).reshape(2, 2)

temp_da = xr.DataArray(
    temp,
    dims=['isobaricInhPa', 'y', 'x'],
    coords={
        'isobaricInhPa': isobaricInhPa,
        'latitude': (['y', 'x'], latitude),
        'longitude': (['y', 'x'], longitude)
    }
)

upper_press = 950

interpolated_temp = temp_da.interp(isobaricInhPa=upper_press)

I got something that is working without throwing me an error, except the values are not correct. It is returning [[1. 2.][3. 4.]]
    unique_pressures = xr.DataArray(
        np.array([[950, 950], [950, 950]], dtype=np.float32),
        dims=['y', 'x'],
        coords={'latitude': (['y', 'x'], latitude), 'longitude': (['y', 'x'], longitude)}
    )
    
    def interpolate_temperature(pressure, isobaricInhPa, temperature):
        return np.interp(pressure, isobaricInhPa, temperature)
    
    interpolated_temp = xr.apply_ufunc(
        interpolate_temperature,
        unique_pressures,              
        temp_da['isobaricInhPa'],      
        temp_da,                     
        input_core_dims=[[], ['isobaricInhPa'], ['isobaricInhPa']],
        output_core_dims=[[]],
        vectorize=True,              
        dask='parallelized',           
        output_dtypes=[float]           
    )


What kind of error do you get when upper_press is an array or what is the problem that you refer to by stating "xarray cannot do the interpolation"?  When I set to e.g. upper_press = np.array([925, 950, 975]) I get the expected results which is a DataArray with the shape (3, 2, 2) where the values are interpolated to the new pressure coordinates.
